# How to get two arrays of obiects by one column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi i have on table with categories with foreign key to herself where parent_id is the same that id in this table. I want to get two arrays of objects. First with categories where

> parent_id=0

and second with subcategories. But I dont know how can I catch this subcategories. I have this:

```
$category= Category::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
dd($category[0]['id']);
$subcategory= Category::where('parent_id', '=', (($category[0]['id']??)));
```

First $category shouild return me array of categories and second array with subcategories i need adjust id of each object of array $category to each subcategory array. Is it possible or there are other ways?

Comment: I think you might want to look at the `IN ()` syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you define your model relations correctly you can get categories and their subcategories in a much nicer way.

First **define the relations**:

```
class Category extends Model {
  public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }

  public function subcategories() {

  }  return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

You can now **get all parent categories with their subcategories** the following way:

```
$parents = Category::whereParentId(0)->with('subcategories')->get();
```

This will give you list of all parent categories, each of them will have **subcategories** property that will store all subcategories. You can traverse them in the following way:

```
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
  printf("Parent category %s\n", $parent->name);

  foreach ($parent->subcategories as $subcategory) {
    printf("Subcategory %s\n", $subcategory->name);
  }
}
```

Small suggestion: make your **parent_id** nullable and store **NULL** for parent categories instead of **0**, as **0** is not a correct category ID.